# RelaxNG compact schema for either/both elements in either order

Tags: xml, relaxng

I am writing a RelaxNG Compact schema for an XML file where the contents of the `<wrap>` elements must be exactly one of:

```xml
<wrap><a/></wrap>
<wrap><b/></wrap>
<wrap><a/><b/></wrap>
<wrap><b/><a/></wrap>
```

*In English, either `<a/>` or `<b/>` are allowed once each, or both in either order, but **one of them is required to be present**.*

Is there a better (more compact) definition of `WrapElement` than the following?

```
grammar {
  start = 
    element wrap { WrapElement }

  WrapElement =
    (
      element a {empty}, 
      element b {empty}?
    )|(
      element a {empty},
      element b {empty}?
    )
}
```

---

The following is close. It's certainly more terse, it matches all the permitted variations, and disallows the elements from occurring more than once. However, it also incorrectly allows an empty `<wrap/>` element:

```
grammar {
  start = 
    element wrap { WrapElement }

  WrapElement =
    element a {empty}?
    & element b {empty}?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
grammar {
  start = 
    element wrap { (a|b)|(a&b) }

  a = element a {empty}
  b = element b {empty}
}
```